# Unhibernating Windows with desired hiberfile.sys

Tags: windows-7, windows, hibernate

let me say the story before asking question:

1. My computer got hibernated
2. I powered it on to unhibernate
3. It hunged up in the process
4. I powered off computer to exit hung state
5. Windows didn't want to unhibernate anymore and started from scratch
6. I want to recover unsaved notepad so I turned off Windows and in using Linux copied hiberfile.sys to another partition

Tell me please, is it possible to cheat on Windows to make it unhibernate from these copied hiberfile.sys?

I tried to hibernate again, then replacing new hiberfile.sys with copied one but Windows haven't seen that as true hibernation and started from scratch so I guess it check for some signatures in hiberfile. Maybe it is possible to do something about that?

Thanks in advance

Comment: It seems it is possible like I described however it requires edition of hiberfile.sys to set the flag informing about hibernated state according to the file specification

Comment: Might be possible if hiberfile.sys isn't corrupted and more importantly if you know enough about the internal workings of the OS so you can trick Windows into accepting the old file.